# System.ExecutionEngineException in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i am getting this exception while debugging my wp8 app on the device. System.ExecutionEngineException . Upon searching the net, i found suggestions to disable concurrent garbage collection and include that in app.config file. How can i do this on windows phone 8. I don't see that in my project. Where should i include this configuration.

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
     <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Kindly help on this.

Comment: check this [support](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=330900)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

That configuration should go an the app.config file. If your project doesn't have one, then you can add it.

I seriously doubt, though, that this will fix your problem.